# Confuse about angular expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

Here is what I want achieve: when user input some text, I will find the character `a` and using `<em>` tag to emphasize it in another `<label>`, here is my html markup:

```
    <div ng-controller="demoController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input" />
        <label>{{emphasize()}}</label>  
    </div>
```

As showing above, I'm using method `emphasize` in `demoController` to do emphasize job:

```
        myapp.controller('demoController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.input = 'Hello';
            $scope.emphasize = function () {
                return $scope.input.replace(/a/g, '<em>a</em>');
            }
        });
```

But the result is, the angular escape the `<em>` tag. For instance , if I input `apple`, then the label would show `<em>a</em>pple`, not I want: **a**pple.

So why does this happened? Is there a way I can prevent this happen or another way to do it?

Comment: You have to use the ng-sanitize service.

Comment: This so this might help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so a simple `ng-bind-hmtl` will do the trick :

```
<span ng-bind-html="emphasize()"></span>
```

But this is not really safe so it's always better to add this on your controller :

```
myapp.controller('demoController', function ($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.input = 'angularJS';
            $scope.emphasize = function () {
                var res = $scope.input.replace(/a/g, '<em>a</em>');
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(res);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

add a filter to your module:

```
myapp.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (a) { return $sce.trustAsHtml(a) };
}]);
```

and in your view:

```
<span ng-bind-html="emphasize() | unsafe"></span
```